# JAVA Google Maps API : set boundaries depending on zoom value

Tags: java, android-studio, google-maps

I'm trying to update the camera boundaries every time the zoom value changes. After checking the doc, I found that it's possible to extend the current boundaries by using method `LatLngBounds Including(LatLng point)` which return the smallest LatLngBounds that contains the LatLng point. So I made this code :

```java
// I save the initial zoom value and I test if it changes
double zoom = mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom;
        if (zoom!= mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom){
// I create a new Bounds which is proportional to the difference of the previous and the new zoom value by including a new point in the boundaries
            LatLng chgtBounds = new LatLng(ParisBounds.getCenter().latitude+(mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom-zoom)*0.001,ParisBounds.getCenter().longitude+(mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom-zoom)*0.001);
            zoom = mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom;
// I apply this new bounds on the map and it automatically delete the previous one
            mMap.setLatLngBoundsForCameraTarget(ParisBounds.including(chgtBounds));
         }
```

I create a new variable that save the zoom value to know when the user is zooming in the map. When he does it, a new boundaries is created by increasing the previous one by a thousandth of the zoom value (not sure it's the right fraction tho but the idea is the same). However, i think those lines are only executed once at the app's launching. Is there a way to execute them eternally ?
I tried a `while(true)` but then the app doesn't launch at all.

Comment: Seems like you'd want the _current_ zoom level, not the maximum available zoom.  To get the current zoom level `mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom`: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/reference/com/google/android/libraries/maps/model/CameraPosition#public-final-float-zoom .  Note also zoom values get larger as one zooms in - not sure if that is what you intend with your "auto-scaling" of bounds.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about this method which is way better. My goal is that when the user is zooming in the map (zoom value increasing), the zone where the camera can move is getting larger to ensure the whole zone is visible. However i figured out I need to substract the previous zoom value with the new one otherwise the Bounds will just get bigger and bigger.

Answer (score 0):

Current zoom level is obtained from:

```
mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom
```

See [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/reference/com/google/android/libraries/maps/model/CameraPosition#public-final-float-zoom).

The max zoom (used in OP code) is the maximum possible zoom based on current camera position and tile type in use.